# Eclipse Android Plugins

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Eclipse Juno IDE Service Release 2.

Basically, I don't know much about Android ADT,SDK,AVD, Tools, plugins and all.

SIC: I don't want to download full ADT again.

I want to install all the latest tools left for android for my Eclipse. I have done with the following (latest version downloaded today) :

[image]

And now, I want to add other plugins as well (please tell me what's left).
Also , I have downloaded and installed SDK Tools today (again, latest version).

Following are the files I downloaded and installed (SDK Tools) for latest version (exe file was of 88 MB or something)..

[image]

I am also unable to open SDK Manager from both Eclipse and Windows explorer. So, please don't suggest me to open SDK Manager and check this and this.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

no other way other than opening sdk manager.

SDK - Software Development Kit - It is a development kit particular for different platforms. They are needed to integrate java with that particual platform.
AVD - Android Virtual Device - An android phones inside your computer. Whenever u r building an app, rather than trying it everytime in your phone, u can use AVD. It opens Android OS.

1) u need to download buid-tools

2) AVD manager (if u dont already have it)

3) System Images - as mentioned above about AVD, it runs android OS inside your computer. So to run android, u need its system images (if u want to run android kitkat, u nedd system images for that version)

Comment: Yes, I got your point and I know about running application on emulator. But please tell why I am not able to open SDK manager. I tried editing "android.bat" file as well to specify the "java.exe" file path. I already have AVD installed, but what to do with SDK manager (I am unable to open that)

Comment: have u tried running SDK manger (not from eclipse) from its path?

Comment: Yes. I tried running it from folder and "Run as administrator" as well. It flashes for a while and then goes off.

Comment: umm... may be a corrupt download. try downloading it again. may be because u dont have platform-tools folder in sdk

Comment: well this is a long story. I was having SDK tools which was of older version. I was creating a simple app using 2 activities. App was running good on Eclipse emulator and other emulators. That version had that platform-tools and each n every folder in it. Then also, I was not able to open SDK Manager.

Comment: try changing path. copy entire sdk folder to some another location and try to open it form there

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I have done that as well. Again, not solved !! Please don't bang your head just like me. :D

Comment: haha.. seems u r in some serious deep trouble. try changing your computer, if this doesnt help, try changing your house, if still doesnt work, try changing ur country. i m sure u will get it working somewhere near mars :p

Comment: haha.. True ! But I will find a way for sure. Computer Science ppl don't loose hope